# Windows 7 can't delete a folder that shows but doesn't seem to exist

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, powershell

So I have a directory in my `Downloads` directory that has the following properties:

I've deleted everything in the folder.
I can see it as a folder in the regular `Downloads` window.
It's not listed when running `dir` in `powershell`.
It's listed when running `dir` in `cmd`.

I can open it in the regular window, but I cannot create any file inside of it.
You can create a sub folder (the ui shows the admin-shield next to the create folder option).

When typing `rmdir` in `cmd` and adding the first letters of the folder, tab-completion will give you the full folder-name. When then running the command the prompt says that it cannot find the search path.

Even if I've created a subfolder, I cannot cd into the folder in `cmd` with the same error-message as when I try to delete it.

Comment: Boot to a live Ubuntu software environment and delete the file

Comment: What is "live Ubuntu software environment"? Do I need to download and install some specific linux-software to delete this folder?

Comment: What does your research indicate?

Comment: Well Google tell me that you're the only person on internet who has ever mentioned a ["live Ubuntu software environment"](https://tinyurl.com/ycl5vr8n). The reason I asked this question here is because I'm wondering if there's some way to delete it that I've missed. I get that your suggestion is that I must install another OS on the computer to delete this empty folder. I'll leave the question up in case there actually is an easy way that I'm not aware of. If the only way to delete the folder is to install another OS I might just leave it there :)

Comment: I live Linux environment it's not difficult you download the ISO then boot to it without installing the OS.  [..........](https://www.google.se/search?ei=6aR8WfbMMeXj0gLo1a6QCQ&q=%22live+Ubuntu+environment%22&oq=%22live+Ubuntu+environment%22&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3..0i8i30k1.3227.4520.0.4869.9.9.0.0.0.0.255.1770.0j6j3.9.0....0...1.1.64.mobile-gws-serp..7.2.368...0i8i13i30k1.BSyqRnQPmDs)

Comment: Does it show up in PowerShell if you run `dir -Force`? If so, what is its Mode?

Comment: I was helping a friend I was staying with over the weekend, so unfortunately I can't try that. But comment with update the next time I'm there :)